# How does one assign a NodeJS query to a global array variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am fairly new to Javascript and am currently working on a project using a MySQL server and NodeJS.

The problem I am having is that when I attempt to push the results of the MySQL query to a global array, the array comes back completely empty. Is there something I am doing wrong or some additional steps that someone can explain to me?

Relevant code:

```
var itemList = [];
var siteList = [];

function getItems(){
        con.connect(function(err) {
            try{
                if (err) throw err;
                    con.query("SELECT DISTINCT ProductURL FROM products;", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                    for (i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                        itemList.push(result[i].ProductURL);
                }
            });
            } finally{
                con.end();
            }
        });

async function another_function() {
 //Does some stuff with the information in the itemList array and inputs to siteList
}

async function anofuncV2() {
  //does more stuff with the information provided by another_function
}

let result = await getItems();
itemList.forEach(another_function);
anofuncV2(siteList);
```

The connection itself is fine and tested as well as a console.log right after the array push comes back with the correct information.

Additional note: I do need it as a global array for the other functions to work properly, I do know I could put it after the push to work, but that isn't what Im looking for

Edit 1: I understand that the code is asynchronous, but the entire concept of asynchronous code confuses me not matter how much I research it. So if someone could give a simple explanation that would be wonderful.

What I understand:

- It runs at the same time as synchronous code causing the other code to run   before the information can be input into the array

Answer (score 0):

That is how asyncronous code works in JavaScript.

> Additional note: I do need it as a global array for the other
> functions to work properly, I do know I could put it after the push to
> work, but that isn't what Im looking for

You need to await the result from the `getItems` func and only proceed with the execution after it is executed.

Ideally, this is how it should be.

```
var itemList = [];

async function getItems(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.connect(function(err) {
            try {
                if (err) throw err;
                    con.query("SELECT DISTINCT ProductURL FROM products;", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                        for (i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                            itemList.push(result[i].ProductURL);
                    }
                });
                resolve(itemList); 
            } finally {
                con.end();
                reject(undefined) // handle error
            }
        });
    })
}

let result = await getItems(); // this will print values inside of itemList array.
```

Comment: Unfortunately that solution didn't work with my code, but that may be my fault for not providing more information. I have edited the code above to more accurately outline the flow of the program.